# I am trying to enable Transparent window borders in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: unity, themes

I am trying to enable Transparent window borders in Ubuntu 15.04. Is there a way to get this done? or are they any other transparent themes that can be installed in Ubuntu 15.04